# How to get array size from HDF5 DataType in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, hdf5

I have HDF5 data files to read with the following DataType

```
HDF5 "testFile.be01" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATATYPE "DRx3" H5T_COMPOUND {
      H5T_ARRAY { [5] H5T_STD_U32LE } "guid";
      H5T_STD_I32LE "version";
      H5T_IEEE_F64LE "d_tot";
      H5T_STD_U32LE "dwl_start_sec";
      ..... // More single item elements left out
      H5T_STD_U32LE "clock_dec_factor";
      H5T_STD_U32LE "num_samps_per_swp";
      H5T_STD_U32LE "sweep_index";
      H5T_STD_U32LE "sequence_dummy";
      H5T_ARRAY { [1000] H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_IEEE_F32LE "f_i";
         H5T_IEEE_F32LE "f_q";
      } } "wb_data";
   }
```

As you can see, in my H5T_COMPOUND I have 2 H5T_ARRAY objects. The first one in this example says it is size 5 and the second is size 1000. Is there a way if I have the DataType object to tell the dimensions of these arrays? I would prefer to use the C++ library, but C code is fine too.

```
// Open the file and datatype
std::string path = "/data/testFile.be01";
H5::H5File file(path, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
H5::DataType datatype = file.openDataType("DRx3");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have to get just the DataType object from the file, I can get a more useful subclass object and get my CompoundType object instead. Then I can get the ArrayType member and query it for its dimension size.

```
// Open the file, dataset, and dataspace
std::string path = "/data/testFile.be01";
H5::H5File file(path, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
H5::CompType datatype = file.openCompType("DRx3");
hsize_t wbDataSize[1];
datatype.getMemberArrayType(datatype.getMemberIndex("wb_data")).getArrayDims(wbDataSize);
```